# Kafka: 1-to-many join

Tags: java, apache-kafka

basically I was wondering what happens if I have topic1 and topic2, given that topic1 can have N topic2 elements.

Topic1 being events for a user, and topic2 being configurations for that user. As a first step I would match them via key, to filter out configs from topic2 that don't belong to that user, but then I would still have multiple matches. I would need to add more filters to topic2 to find the exact match, but I don't know if this is possible after the join-by-key.

I read this: [Kafka Stream and KTable One-to-Many Relationship Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275301/kafka-stream-and-ktable-one-to-many-relationship-join)

but I'm still wondering how can I process that data once is filtered and the joins are made? If I end up with a ktable with multiple entries (1 repeated key for N values). How can I process that in my stream/topology?

Also, would I need a globalKTable, since the right-side topic (configs) could be in different partitions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> Topic1 being events for a user, and topic2 being configurations for
> that user. As a first step I would match them via key, to filter out
> configs from topic2 that don't belong to that user, but then I would
> still have multiple matches. I would need to add more filters to
> topic2 to find the exact match, but I don't know if this is possible
> after the join-by-key.

You do not need to do all this filtering. You need to look at the join-semantics in KStreams API and determine what approach works for your application.

Give this a read: [Crossing the Streams – Joins in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/)

From what I can tell from your question, it looks like a **KStream-GlobalKTable Join** would do what you are looking for - assuming that the userconfiguration is global state. There is support for both **inner and left** joins in the API for KStream-GlobalKTable joins.

> If I end up with a ktable with multiple entries (1 repeated key for N
> values). How can I process that in my stream/topology?

The output of a join operation is itself either a KTable (changelog stream) or event stream (potentially windowed in the kstream-kstream join case). But in the end you process the output stream in your topology just as you would any other operation.

Comment: Thanks for your message. So I'm assuming that even if I end up with a 1-N stream, the processing doesn't differ from a "normal" stream processing. Just repeated messages with the same key and different value. OK.

Comment: Regarding the GlobalKTable, it's what I planned on using, however I have a problem, which might be a new question on its own in this site. Since my topic for the globalktable doesn't match the key of the left-side stream, there's never going to be a match. Stream key: userId. GlobalKTable topic key: userid/randomUUID . Since I cannot repartition a table, would it be possible to modify the topic's key and use an intermediate topic to convert it to a globalkTable? Either that or I should try a different approach. Thanks

Comment: You can do foreign key joins (depending on your version): https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-summit-2020/crossing-the-streams-the-new-streaming-foreign-key-join-feature-in-kafka-streams/

Comment: In the end I did the following: I kept the original keys of each topic. I did a group+aggregation in the 2nd topic. That goes to a temp topic, which I read and convert to a globalKtable resulting in key: user id - value: List<values> . So I have a list of configurations per user id. Which is what I wanted in the end. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Just one last question, do you know if it's possible, in the same topology, to output a stream to a topic with to(), and in the same topology create a kstream/globalktable from that new topic? I mean, if I just produced results into it, can I read it right away? Thanks

Comment: You can do that but you might have to use the `Processor API` for lower level of control. Also, I wouldn't do that if you can help it - there is a performance penalty for sending messages over the network and if you send it to Kafka just to receive it again then it would be better if you could just forward that data internally.

Comment: Got it. My only problem is just that I wanted to filter some messages from a topic (for which I understand I need a kstream and filter()), group them by key and aggregate() (basically to have (k: userid, v: List<configs>) and then convert that filtered topic to a globalKtable to join it to another kstream, so I would need a temporary topic to have the filtered kstream become a globalktable. Although I'm thinking that maybe I could apply the filter in the valueJoiner of both (kstream and globalktable).